# Using C++ ifstream extraction operator>> to read formatted data from a file

Tags: c++, operators, ifstream

As my learning, I am trying to use c++ ifstream and its operator>> to read data from a text file using code below. The text file outdummy.txt has following contents:

```
just dummy
Hello ofstream
555
```

My questions is how to read char data present in the file into a char array or string. How to do this using the ifstream::operator>> in code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    int a;
    string s;
    char buf[100];
    ifstream in("outdummy.txt",ios_base::in);


    in.operator>>(a); //How to read integer? How to read the string data.??

    cout << a;

    in.close();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your example is wrong; you don't even "read the integer correctly". In fact, that line fails and `a` is unchanged, but for some reason you already initialized it to the expected value, so you've blindfolded yourself.

Comment: @Kerrek is right. And he's [provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443787/using-c-ifstream-extraction-operator-to-read-formatted-data-from-a-file/7443877#7443877) the correct and easy-to-use solution -- the `getline` with `string`.

Comment: Why `char[]`? Why not `std::string`?

Comment: @jonsca: My comment was largely rhetorical. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to use formatted input, you have to know in advance what data to expect and read it into variables of the according data type. For example, if you know that the number is always the fifth token, as in your example, you could do this:

```
std::string s1, s2, s3, s4;
int n;

std::ifstream in("outdummy.txt");

if (in >> s1 >> s2 >> s3 >> s4 >> n)
{
  std::cout << "We read the number " << n << std::endl;
}
```

On the other hand, if you know that the number is always on the third line, by itself:

```
std::string line;

std::getline(in, line);  // have line 1
std::getline(in, line);  // have line 2
std::getline(in, line);  // have line 3

std::istringstream iss(line);

if (iss >> n)
{
  std::cout << "We read the number " << n << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, to read a token as a string, you just stream it into a `std::string`. It's important to remember that the formatted input operator works token by token, and tokens are separated by whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines). The usual fundamental choice to make is whether you process a file entirely in tokens (first version), or line by line (second version). For line-by-line processing, you use `getline` first to read one line into a string, and then use a string stream to tokenize the string.

---

A word about validation: You cannot know whether a formatted extraction will actually succeed, because that depends on the input data. Therefore, you should *always* check whether an input operation succeeded, and abort parsing if it doesn't, because in case of a failure your variables won't contain the correct data, but you have no way of knowing that later. So always say it like this:

```
if (in >> v) { /* ... */ }            // v is some suitable variable
else { /* could not read into v */ }

if (std::getline(in, line)) { /* process line */ }
else { /* error, no line! */ }
```

The latter construction is usually used in a `while` loop, to read an entire file line by line:

```
while (std::getline(in, line)) { /* process line */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `ifstream` has `ios_base::in` by default. You don't need to specify it.
2. `operator>>` can be invoked directly as an operator: `in >> a`.
3. Reading strings is the same: `in >> s`, but the caveat is that it is whitespace-delimited, so it will read "just" by itself, without "dummy".
4. If you want to read complete lines, use `std::getline(in, s)`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have elected to use C-strings, you can use the [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) method of your `ifstream` object (not `std::getline()` which works with `std::string`s), which will allow you to specify the C-string and a maximum size for the buffer.

Based on what you had, and adding an additional buffer for the second line:

```
char buf[100];
char buf2[100];

in.getline(buf,sizeof(buf));
in.getline(buf2,sizeof(buf2));
in >> a;
```

However, as the other poster has proposed, try using the `std::string` and its methods, it will make your life easier.

Comment: Ewwww. C arrays. Magic numbers. :-(

Comment: @Kerrek Preaching to the choir, but I'm trying to tailor it to his example.

Comment: fair enough, but I think if someone suggests `in.operator>>(a)` in the first place, it's time for a change of clothes :-)

Comment: You serious? :-) But note that it didn't actually work. The error was obscured because the OP didn't validate the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can read file contents and use a [Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) for parsing.

Example:

```
void Parse(const char* buffer, size_t length);
size_t GetBufferSize();

size_t bufferSize = GetBufferSize();
char* buffer = new char[bufferSize];

std::ifstream in("input.txt");
while(in.getline(buffer, bufferSize)) {
    Parse(buffer, in.gcount());
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a tool like [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) to write your parser.

Comment: Dynamically allocating a char array? Seriously? Something wrong with `std::string`?

Comment: I used a dynamically allocated char array to be consistent with the example included in the question. Of course it would be more adequate to use a container such as `string`, `rope` or `vector<char>` instead of a char array in production code and I should have mentioned.

Comment: The question did not dynamically allocate a `char` array.