# Function to parse a text in C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I need to parse a .txt that contains lines with three columns separated by spaces with these types of data:

```
string size_t string
```

What I have to do is save those three parameters in an array of structures. The function I made is:

```
bool setInput(std::istream& input, size_t n_tx_in, input_t *inputs){

    std::string line;

    for(size_t i=0; i< n_tx_in; i++){
        getline(input,line);
    }
    
}
```

And the structure is :

```
typedef struct{
    string tx_id;
    size_t idx;
} outpoint_t;

typedef struct{
    outpoint_t outpoint;
    string addr;
} input_t;
```

I don't know how to split each line and get those three parameters so I can store them in my array of inputs. What should I use ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443787/using-c-ifstream-extraction-operator-to-read-formatted-data-from-a-file) help you get started?

Comment: Can the string themselves contain spaces? If not, the normal stream extract operator `>>` separates on, and by default ignores, space.

Comment: New-line (`\n`) is also a white-space: `getline` is not needed.

Comment: In short, `while (input >> a >> b >> c) [...memorize a, b, c...}`